# webpack dev server: watch arbitrary directory files and reload

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

Is it possible to make webpack-dev-server reload whenever a specified set of arbitrary files changes?

Something along the lines of:

```
devServer: {
    watchTheseFiles: [ 'path/to/files', 'path/to/more/files' ]
}
```

And even more granularly, can I specify a regex of which files to watch?

I'm doing this as a bit of a hack to reload when I trigger certain changes in arbitrary files (they could be `.txt`, `.png`, whatever...)

At the moment, the specified paths in `contentBase` don't seem to trigger reload when files change.

Comment: It's a bit unusual that `contentBase` isn't working. Does watching work otherwise, for example when you change the entry script? On some systems you may need to poll or increase the number of `inotify` watchers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's anything readily available that's better than `contentBase`. `webpack`, `webpack-dev-server` and `webpack-dev-middleware` all expose an [`invalidate(callback)`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/af4cb35784be468c32da5b79c33b88e83cad1257/lib/Watching.js) helper, but it would require you to create your custom script to programmatically manage the compiler, server or middleware to invoke the handler.

Something similar to this that should work across all compilers configured for watching is to add additional files as compilation dependencies and let webpack handle the invalidation. You can also do this when using webpack programmatically, but it's also really easy to write your own plugin and perform this from the configuration. Here's an example:

```
class CustomContextPlugin {
    apply (compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.beforeCompile.tap('CustomContextPlugin', params => {
            params.compilationDependencies.add(
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'robots.txt')
            )
        })
    }
}

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new CustomContextPlugin()
    ]
}
```

It uses the `beforeCompile` hook to add a `robots.txt` file as a compilation dependency. In development where we don't perform any caching, this should cause the development server to reload the page because new chunks were emitted.

There's probably also other options. One thing that comes to mind is maybe having a development entry or some other module that uses [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context), but I think these options would involve more effort.

Comment: Thank you for this response, it pushed me quite far in solving similar issues. Any chance you have ideas on how to add folders to watch? I want to make sure that new files within a specific folder will be added to the watch after creation